# Why are UK celebrities not prosecuted after admitting to drug use?

Tags: united-kingdom, drugs, statute-of-limitations

Frequently, UK celebrities and politicians publish memoirs where they admit to breaking laws related to illegal substance use, yet they never seem to be prosecuted after openly admitting it. A recent example is David Cameron, the previous prime minister, which is especially interesting since during his tenor he resisted a reform of drug laws, which means many people who did nothing worse end up being prosecuted themselves.

As far as I know, UK law does not have a statute of limitations, so the fact that these crimes occurred long ago is not by itself a reason to let it go. The publication of these memoirs should provide sufficient evidence that the crime took place, or at least form the basis of an investigation.

Yes, I am aware of ([Why are drug using celebrities free?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/70812/why-are-drug-using-celebrities-free)) but the answers there are US specific and I'm interested in a UK perspective.

Comment: Drug use isn't a crime in the jurisdiction.

Comment: I spend half an hour writing an answer, just for it be closed. Facepalm :)

Comment: @Rick - perhaps your answer could still be added to the original question that closed this one?

Comment: @Lag not sure I understand correctly - in the David Cameron case he certainly admitted to using cannabis in a jurisdiction (Eton) where it is illegal to do so.

Comment: Possession, supply and production were and are offences. I don't think 'use' is an offence. I could be wrong!

Comment: @firtydank Dealing with school rules broken year ago is up to the staff at Eton to deal with.

Comment: Possession of drugs for personal use can be a crime, but is only prosecuted if it's in the public interest. [You can read the English guidelines here](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/drug-offences), and if you've smoked cannabis in private and have a clean record, there's a good chance you'll not be prosecuted even if it was recent and there is overwhelming evidence.

Answer (score -1):

### In 1963, I shot JFK

Why am I not prosecuted?

See how easy it is to admit to crimes no one can prove you did?

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but I am not particularly convinced by it. We are not talking about random people on the internet (no offence I hope!), but well known people who admit to crimes using a solicited channel (i.e. a book "written" and published by them)

Comment: @firtydank - Confession, of its own, wouldn't be sufficient for the Director of Public Prosecutions to bring a case in the UK. And no one is going to risk bringing a case if the main evidence is "David Cameron said so".

Comment: Yes, this a useless answer.